# Why I can't add a brand new property-value to this JSON object using JavaScript? Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I have to use only plain old JS to add a brand new field to a **JSON** object like this:

```
    var dateFirestForecast = (new Date(firstForecastRetrieved.start_date)).toISOString().split('T')[0];

    var day_1 = JSON.parse(`
        {
            "day-1": {}
        }
    `);

    day_1.day-1.start_date = dateFirestForecast;
```

In my code I have something like the previous snippet.

The first line contains a string like **2017-11-05**.

Then I have a **day_1** JSON object containing a **day-1** field (which is a JSON object in turn).

I am trying to add a brand new **"start_date"** field to this object by:

```
day_1.day-1.start_date = dateFirestForecast;
```

to obtain something like this as final result:

```
{
    "day-1": {
        "start_date": "2017-11-02",
    }
}
```

but doing in this way I am obtaining this JavaScript error in the console related to this last line:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
day_1.day-1.start_date = dateFirestForecast;
```

That `-` in there is a subtraction. Since it's supposed to be part of the value's name, you'll need to use bracket access, instead:

```
day_1["day-1"].start_date = dateFirestForecast;
```